# Jupyter: export as PDF when notebook itself has LaTeX included

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

I have an IPython notebook, and I want to export it as a pdf with latex. This works for notebooks which do not contain LaTeX themselves, but when I directly use latex inside the notebook and then try to import it as an pdf, I get the following error:

```html
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "['xelatex', 'notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
... more sty files (I shortened the log)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
No file notebook.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.393     \begin{matrix}
                        
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.393     \begin{matrix}
                        
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

I honestly don't know what I should do with this.
What I also noticed by using the command line was, that generating the tex file works fine. But then converting it to a pdf wiht pdflatex yields the same error as above.

The notebook uses latex like this:
[image]